# Problem with environment variable

Tags: 20.04

I have a problem with environment variables, I have set the GRAALVM_HOME for version 22.3 but for some reason it keeps detecting 22.1
I have use the /etc/profile.d/jdk_home.sh file to set myh preference but as for what I can see the file /etc/profile.d/apps-bin-path.sh is doing something before that overrides my preference.
This is the terminal output

```
linux@alandec:~$ native-image --version
GraalVM 22.1.0.1 Java 17 CE (Java Version 17.0.3+7-jvmci-22.1-b06)
linux@alandec:~$ echo $GRAALVM_HOME 
/home/linux/graalvm-svm-java17-linux-gluon-22.1.0.1-Final
linux@alandec:~$ PS4='+$BASH_SOURCE> ' BASH_XTRACEFD=7 bash -xl 7>file.log
linux@alandec:~$ echo $GR
$GRAALVM_HOME  $GROUPS        
linux@alandec:~$ echo $GRAALVM_HOME 
/home/linux/Documentos/graalvm-ce-java17-22.3.0/
linux@alandec:~$ native-image --version
GraalVM 22.3.0 Java 17 CE (Java Version 17.0.5+8-jvmci-22.3-b08)
linux@alandec:~$
```

Answer (score 0):

As per [this documentation](https://graalvm.github.io/native-build-tools/0.9.6/graalvm-setup.html), run the below commands to set the correct path and install the native image:

```
export GRAALVM_HOME=/home/${current_user}/path/to/graalvm
$GRAALVM_HOME/bin/gu install native-image
```

You could then run the below again and check the version:

```
native-image --version
```